# Linq statement with stored procedure returning column value

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a linq statement that gets a few columns from a table then the last column is a value returned from a stored procedure. The stored procedure returns a `varchar(max)` value because it is doing some recursive look-ups and can be very long.

For the code below I have used "CalculatedValueSproc" as the name of the stored procedure that is filling a variable called "CalculatedValue" which is just a string.

```
var users = 
    (from u in _db.Users
        where u.Deleted == false
        orderby u.Name
         select new User
         {
             Id = u.Id,
             Name = u.Name,
             CalculatedValue = _db.CalculatedValueSproc(u.Id),
         }).ToList();
```

When this is executed it errors:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.String] CalculatedValueSproc(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Not sure where I am going wrong but any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Robert

Comment: If you want to use Store procedure inside query you cane use exec http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360360/linq-to-sql-stored-procedures-cannot-be-used-inside-queries

Answer (score 2):

It is trying to convert `CalculatedValue = _db.CalculatedValueSproc(u.Id)` into SQL statement, and it can't.  But you can call it after it's a materialized list and not a SQL statement.  Executing the `ToList()` will fire the SQL and get results allowing you to then call the SPROC per record.

The `SELECT()` function I added is working with full blown POCO's and is not going to have to be converted to a SQL statement.

Try this:

```
var users = 
(from u in _db.Users
    where u.Deleted == false
    orderby u.Name).ToList().
Select( u => new User
     {
         Id = u.Id,
         Name = u.Name,
         CalculatedValue = _db.CalculatedValueSproc(u.Id),
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just like you can not call sp with column value directly in one sql query.
You can separate the result as below:

```
var users = 
    (from u in _db.Users
        where u.Deleted == false
        orderby u.Name
         select new User
         {
             Id = u.Id,
             Name = u.Name,
             CalculatedValue = null,
         }).ToList();

foreach (var user in users)
{
  user.CalculatedValue = _db.CalculatedValueSproc(u.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These steps helped me when I got such problem:

1. Open your EDMX model with XML, find your function and change its attributes as following:

```xml
<Function Name="CalculatedValueSproc" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo" ReturnType="varchar">
  <Parameter Name="Id" Type="numeric" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

Please note that IsComposable attribute is set to true and ReturnType attribute is a type your function returns, in your case it should be varchar.

2. Save EDMX file and rebuild the project.
3. Add your function to your dbContext file:

   ```
   public partial class YourEntities
   {
       [DbFunction("YourModel.Store", "CalculatedValueSproc")]
       public string CalculatedValueSproc(int? Id)
       {
           throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
       }
   }
   ```
4. Remove these lines of codes (if they are in dbContext file):

   ```
   public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<string>> CalculatedValueSproc(Nullable<int> Id)
   {
       var IdParameter = Id.HasValue ?
       new ObjectParameter("Id", Id) :
       new ObjectParameter("Id ", typeof(int));

       return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable< string >>("CalculatedValueSproc", Id);
   ```

   }
5. Save EDMX file and rebuild the project.